# Пропадают записи в crontab

Tags: linux, cron

В последнее время пропадают записи из кронтаба чудесным образом вообще, в первый раз когда произошло подумал что какое то серьезное обновление произошло и записи подтерлись, но это случилось и во второй раз, подскажите куда копать вообще, а то не очень хорошо на боевом сервере. Задания из под рута Linux Debian 8

Поискал в сети есть вариант что это из за того что вместо табов стоят пробелы проверяю.

---

**обновление из «ответа»**

Ответ оказался совсем простым: промахнулся, и вместо `crontab -e` написал `crontab -r`.

Comment: система виртуализирована?

Comment: нет, физ сервер на нем стоит линь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> куда копать вообще

направления розысков (порядок — случайный)

- ваша ошибка/невнимательность
- ошибка/невнимательность ваших коллег
- сторонее программное обеспечение, взятое из «левых» источников (типа «официальных сайтов» и т.п.)
- взлом (включает утечку/подбор паролей, эксплуатацию какой-нибудь [не]известной уязвимости какой-нибудь программы и т.д. и т.п.)

---

очень общие и поверхностные рекомендации:

- внимательный просмотр логов, предшествующих изменению файла
- просмотр вывода программы `last` (подробнее — `$ man last`)
- проверка контрольных сумм файлов, входящих в пакеты (пакет [debsums](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/ru/man1/debsums.1.html))
- «слежка» за изменением файлов с использованием механизма *inotify* (например, с помощью [incron](https://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/incron))